# Changing a string into a comma separated numpy int array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a string that comes in bytes that has commas inside of it.

ex. `b'-8 ,0 ,54 ,-30 ,28'`

I first change it into a string using

```
msg = str(msg, 'utf-8')
```

This part works. However I need to make this string into a numpy int array. I have tried splitting at the commas, but I wind up just getting a 1 dimensional numpy array. I would like for each value in the array to be split by a comma.

```
msg = str(msg, 'utf-8')

z = [x.strip() for x in msg.split(',')]

x = np.array(z)
y = x.astype(np.int)
```

The error I get is

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (5,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Thank for the help!

Comment: What result were you hoping to get?  What distinguishes the "1 dimensional numpy array" you got from the "numpy int array" you want?

Comment: @jasonharper I want a 1 by 5 array, ex. 1 row and 5 columns. This is because the array is being fed into a neural network.

Comment: `np.array(b'-8 ,0 ,54 ,-30 ,28'.decode().split(','),int)` produces `array([ -8,   0,  54, -30,  28])`.  Shape is (5,).  If you want something else like (1,5) or (5,1) use `reshape`.

Comment: Applying `.reshape((1, 5))` to the array would do that, although the error message makes it sound like something else is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

All you are missing is a conversion from a string to an int inside of your list comprehension:

```py
msg = str(msg, 'utf-8')
z = [int(x.strip()) for x in msg.split(',')]
x = np.array(z)
```

`split()` returns an array of strings, so you were getting `z` as an array of strings that look like numbers. `int()` is able to convert such strings into their numerical representations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Sorry I wasn't very clear. Anyway to change your answer to reflect the edit in my question regarding separation?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [213]: b'-8 ,0 ,54 ,-30 ,28'.decode()                                                                     
Out[213]: '-8 ,0 ,54 ,-30 ,28'
In [214]: b'-8 ,0 ,54 ,-30 ,28'.decode().split(',')                                                          
Out[214]: ['-8 ', '0 ', '54 ', '-30 ', '28']
In [215]: np.array(b'-8 ,0 ,54 ,-30 ,28'.decode().split(','), dtype=int)                                     
Out[215]: array([ -8,   0,  54, -30,  28])
In [216]: np.array(b'-8 ,0 ,54 ,-30 ,28'.decode().split(','), dtype=int).reshape(-1,1)                       
Out[216]: 
array([[ -8],
       [  0],
       [ 54],
       [-30],
       [ 28]])
```